# Python format string from generator

Tags: python, formatting, generator

I am looking to format a string where the generator returns words these words should be joined together with `/` between them and then on more word added to the end.

The string should also start with a `/`

e.g.

```
final_word = "/" + "/".join(gen_function) + "/" + word
```

If gen_function returns ['one', 'two', 'three'] and word = 'complete'

The final_word would be

```
/one/two/three/complete
```

Is there a more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.6+, you can use format strings:

```
f"/{'/'.join(gen_function)}/{word}"
```

Other than that, your solution is fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
my_string = '/' + '/'.join(my_list)
```

This will return /a/b/c/d